# Incorporating Maven into existing Java project in VSCode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have an existing project that I have been working on for some time, however I've run into the problem of needing to use JSON reading dependencies which are not included for some reason. I want to use Maven to do this, how do I convert my current project into a Maven project so that I can add dependencies easily without losing progress?

Installing the library manually didn't actually allow me to implement the imports for some reason, so hopefully using Maven will fix the issue.

Comment: Create a new Maven project from scratch and copy your existing files in `src` folder. If you face a specific error or question, come back to us :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new maven project in vscode and copy your code files to the new project.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_create-a-new-java-project*

[image]